# Hiding grid columns with the App SDK 2.0

Tags: rally, appsdk2

It would appear that the `hideable` setting for columns within a `rallygrid` component has no effect when applied. I have used this setting in the past with the `gridpanel` and had it work just fine but it appears to have been disabled with the `rallygrid`component. I would like it if users were able to hide grid columns that weren't nessessary. Is this possible using a `rallygrid` by some other means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the config:

```
disableColumnMenus: false
```

This should allow users to select which columns are hide-able, and some other column choices.